# implementing pearson's correlation coefficient for 3 variables in scipy.stats

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, correlation

To understand the association between variables, I want to implement a Pearson's correlation coefficient test. Although I know how to do it for three variables in pandas, I don't know how to do that in scipy.stats. Since I also want to know the P-value of these correlations, scipy.stats is my best solution. Can anyone help me how to implement persons correlation coefficient in scipy for 3 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to produce 3 pairs to calculate the correlation for:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import scipy.stats

list_of_vars = [array_1, array_2, array_3]
results = [scipy.stats.pearsonr(*pair) for pair in combinations(list_of_vars, 2)]
```

the `results` will be a list of 2-tuples of `(r, p_value)`, e.g:

```
[(0.3488605505012684, 0.7731373652607254),      # for <array_1, array_2>
 (-0.7590110031075414, 0.45136569429566353),    # for <array_1, array_3>
 (0.3453846068421791, 0.7754969404436115)]      # for <array_2, array_3>
```